# Converting table with columns as level into tree Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown in image and want to create a tree hierarchy out of it.

[image]

trying to do this using oracle sql.

Comment: And where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have parent-child hierarchy to perform that. I used the `HR` default schema to execute this query:

```
with t(val, lvl) as (
select sys_connect_by_path(employee_id, '/'), level lvl
  from employees
 start with manager_id is null
connect by manager_id = prior employee_id
), t_corr(bigboss, boss, employee) as (
select case 
         when lvl > 1 then
           substr(val, instr(val, '/', 1, 1) + 1, instr(val, '/', 1, 2) - 1 - instr(val, '/', 1, 1)) 
         else
           substr(val, instr(val, '/', 1, 1) + 1)
       end bigboss
     , case 
         when lvl = 1 then null
         when lvl = 2 then
           substr(val, instr(val, '/', 1, 2) + 1)
         else
       substr(val, instr(val, '/', 1, 2) + 1, instr(val, '/', 1, 3) - 1 - instr(val, '/', 1, 2))
       end boss
     , case
     when lvl in (1, 2) then null
         else substr(val, instr(val, '/', 1, 3) + 1) 
       end employee
  from t
 where lvl < 4
)
select e1.last_name || ' ' || e1.first_name bigboss
     , e2.last_name || ' ' || e2.first_name boss
     , e3.last_name || ' ' || e3.first_name employee
  from t_corr
     , employees e1
     , employees e2
     , employees e3
 where t_corr.bigboss = e1.employee_id(+)
   and t_corr.boss = e2.employee_id(+)
   and t_corr.employee = e3.employee_id(+)
/

BIGBOSS              BOSS                 EMPLOYEE
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
King Steven
King Steven          Kochhar Neena
King Steven          Kochhar Neena        Greenberg Nancy
King Steven          Kochhar Neena        Whalen Jennifer
King Steven          Kochhar Neena        Higgins Shelley
King Steven          De Haan Lex
King Steven          De Haan Lex          Hunold Alexander
King Steven          Raphaely Den
...
King Steven          Fripp Adam           Atkinson Mozhe
King Steven          Fripp Adam           Marlow James
King Steven          Fripp Adam           Olson TJ

29 rows selected.
```

If you want to make hierarchy from the table:

```
with t(a, b, c, d, e) as (
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e1' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e2' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e3' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e4' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e5' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e6' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e7' from dual union all
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e8' from dual
), tt (a, b, c, d, e) as (
  select a, lpad(b, 4, '-'), lpad(c, 8, '-'), lpad(d, 12, '-'), lpad(e, 16, '-') from t
)
select unique dd 
  from tt
unpivot(
  dd for col1 in (a, b, c, d, e)
)
order by 1 

DD
--------------------
a
---b
-------c
-----------d
--------------e1
--------------e2
--------------e3
--------------e4
--------------e5
--------------e6
--------------e7
--------------e8
```

Comment: I know how to create a hierarchy but in my table first column contains top nodes, second contains nodes on level two and so on... I have five columns and want to create a tree with 5 levels. Please refer to this link- (http://imgur.com/OrvKgCU)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your table structure like this :

```
emp_id          emp_name          emp_emp_id (boss of emp_id)
1                    BigBoss          NULL
2                    Boss             1
3                    Emp1             2
4                    Emp2             2
```

The you can easyly use connect by Oracle KeyWord to recover the hierarchy tree.
Doc Here => http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: I know how to create a hierarchy but in my table first column contains top nodes, second contains nodes on level two and so on... I have five columns and want to create a tree with 5 levels.please refer to this link- (http://imgur.com/OrvKgCU)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example of `SCOTT.EMP` table to create the hierarchy.

```
SQL> SELECT empno,
  2    level,
  3    Lpad(ename,LENGTH(ename) + LEVEL * 10 - 10,'-') tree,
  4    job,
  5    mgr
  6  FROM emp
  7    START WITH mgr        IS NULL
  8    CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
  9  /

     EMPNO      LEVEL TREE                                JOB              MGR
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------- --------- ----------
      7839          1 KING                                PRESIDENT
      7566          2 ----------JONES                     MANAGER         7839
      7788          3 --------------------SCOTT           ANALYST         7566
      7876          4 ------------------------------ADAMS CLERK           7788
      7902          3 --------------------FORD            ANALYST         7566
      7369          4 ------------------------------SMITH CLERK           7902
      7698          2 ----------BLAKE                     MANAGER         7839
      7499          3 --------------------ALLEN           SALESMAN        7698
      7521          3 --------------------WARD            SALESMAN        7698
      7654          3 --------------------MARTIN          SALESMAN        7698
      7844          3 --------------------TURNER          SALESMAN        7698
      7900          3 --------------------JAMES           CLERK           7698
      7782          2 ----------CLARK                     MANAGER         7839
      7934          3 --------------------MILLER          CLERK           7782

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

There are three important things to understand, `START WITH`, `CONNECT BY PRIOR` and `LEVEL`.

**START WITH** – Specifies the root of the hierarchy. To determine where to start parsing from.

**CONNECT BY PRIOR** – This explains the relationship between the parent and the child. CONNECT BY PRIOR `empno = mgr` means we are traversing from `top to bottom`. Reversing it would mean `bottom to top`.

**LEVEL** - It acts like a pseudo column that shows the level or rank of the particular row in the hierarchy.

Comment: I am not having any parent child relationship in my table. How can I create one

Comment: Do you have access to SCOTT schema? if you look at employee table, you would understand what is required.

Comment: I know how to create a hierarchy but in my table first column contains top nodes, second contains nodes on level two and so on... I have five columns and want to create a tree with 5 levels.